# Create a Distributed Application using AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud, distributed-computing

Using AWS cloud services I would like to create a truly distributed application (ie where every node of the network is actually located in a different place) , based on a distributed consensus algorithm (similar to RAFT). Unfortunately I don't know AWS services very well and I only have in mind what I have to do, but I still have a lot of doubts about what services should I use (after having understood how they work).
In summary (as in the figure) what I would like to do is this:

[image]

1) User can use an API, called "main API" in the image (providing certain parameters). This API "starts the algorithm" by communicating directly with one or more remote machines.

2) Each machine has its own API (with its own HTTP address), and for this reason it is able to communicate with all the other machines. Each of these machines runs the same consensus algorithm.

3)At the end of the algorithm (ie when a machine chooses the value) it writes this value into a database (DB in the image). For example, there may be a database for every single machine, but it is not mandatory.

So my question is about which AWS services are right for this purpose and above all how to best use these services for my task.

- What is the best service for creating your own machines and exposing them to the world via API? I only know (very poorly) the **API Gateway** service, but I don't know absolutely how to "own" remote machines and databases.
- What is the best way to associate the algorithm code with a single machine? I was thinking of using **AWS Lambda** (a program is called in response to a certain HTTP call on the respective API). As for the output, I thought I was writing to the **Dynamo DB** database.
- I would like to send to the main API parameters that specify the number of machines (and DBs) that will be used (maybe they could be "dynamically allocated"). Can you do this thing? For example I could tell the main API that I want to execute the algorithm with 3 machines and therefore only 3 remote machines (I don't care what) will work.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could do this with the AWS Lambda + API Gateway, or EC2, ECS, or EKS services, or some combination of those services, depending on your concrete compute resource needs and if you prefer using Docker or Kubernetes, etc. Your question is too broad to provide an exact answer. Any of those services can serve HTTP requests endpoints.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know AWS services well. Is it possible to do everything I said only using AWS Lambda + API Gateway?

Comment: It may be possible using AWS Lambda, but you need to look into the limitations of the Lambda environment, which include max available RAM and max request time, etc. The general idea is possible but your requirements are too vague to say specifically.

Comment: The algorithm itself is very simple and there should be no problems.  The thing that really interests me is having a copy of the function in a different machine, which can be invoked via API. I would like to do as described in the simplest way possible.

Comment: All cloud compute services allow you to have "a copy of the function in a different machine". With AWS Lambda each time you execute it, it may end up executing on a different machine. The level of distributed computing you are looking for is really just the standard way you do computing in a cloud environment. If you think it will work on Lambda then I say go with that.

Comment: So I can create the same Lambda function but replicate it as many times as I want in different machines and make them talk to each other via API? Could you link me some example of using this thing?

Comment: You don't need to replicate an identical Lambda function across multiple machines. Lambda is serverless, so you don't have to think in terms of "machines". Each time you make a call to invoke a lambda function AWS will spin up an instance of it. If you want them to be longer lived and continuously sending traffic between each other, then Lambda won't work for you, but maybe you need to rethink your design to work in a serverless environment. Your question is too vague for me to give a clear answer on what will work for you.